# OpenShift V3 and incremental builds

Tags: openshift

I have some issues using incremental builds with the image ruby-22-centos7.

I added the following script "save-artifacts" to .sti/bin directory :

```
#!/bin/sh -e

pushd ${HOME} >/dev/null

if [ -d ./bundle/ruby ]; then
  tar cf - bundle/ruby
fi

popd >/dev/null
```

I have this error during the build steps :

I0330 13:53:05.022524       1 sti.go:213] Using assemble from image:///usr/libexec/s2i
15  I0330 13:53:05.022544       1 sti.go:213] Using run from image:///usr/libexec/s2i
16  I0330 13:53:05.022551       1 sti.go:213] Using save-artifacts from upload/src/.sti/bin
17  I0330 13:53:05.024552       1 sti.go:142] Existing image for tag 172.30.22.77:5000/blog/blog:latest detected for incremental build
18  I0330 13:53:05.024570       1 sti.go:147] Performing source build from file:///tmp/s2i-build462497527/upload/src
19  I0330 13:53:05.024654       1 sti.go:350] Saving build artifacts from image 172.30.22.77:5000/blog/blog:latest to path /tmp/s2i-build462497527/upload/artifacts
20  I0330 13:53:05.026788       1 docker.go:374] Both scripts and untarred source will be placed in '/tmp'
21  I0330 13:53:05.026820       1 docker.go:510] Creating container using config: {Hostname: Domainname: User: Memory:0 MemorySwap:0 CPUShares:0 CPUSet: AttachStdin:false AttachStdout:true AttachStderr:false PortSpecs:[] ExposedPorts:map[] Tty:false OpenStdin:false StdinOnce:false Env:[] Cmd:[/tmp/scripts/save-artifacts] DNS:[] Image:172.30.22.77:5000/blog/blog:latest Volumes:map[] VolumeDriver: VolumesFrom: WorkingDir: MacAddress: Entrypoint:[] NetworkDisabled:false SecurityOpts:[] OnBuild:[] Mounts:[] Labels:map[]}
22  I0330 13:53:05.685226       1 docker.go:524] Attaching to container
23  I0330 13:53:05.686542       1 docker.go:530] Starting container
24  E0330 13:53:10.836202       1 tar.go:207] Error reading next tar header: io: read/write on closed pipe
25  W0330 13:53:10.859154       1 sti.go:150] Clean build will be performed because of error saving previous build artifacts
26  I0330 13:53:10.859172       1 sti.go:152] ERROR: timeout waiting for tar stream

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: What version of OpenShift are you using? There was an issue with incremental builds in OpenShift Origin 1.1.3 and 1.1.4. I believe has been fixed since then but I haven't myself yet confirmed it.

Comment: Related issues are https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/7708#issuecomment-198271240 and https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image/pull/446